# UICollectionViewCell unavailable in sizeForItemAt

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, swift3, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to animate a cell size change in a collection view.

In 'didSelectItemAt':

```
            collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
                collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
                let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
                let frame = cell?.frame
                cell?.frame = CGRect(x: (frame?.origin.x)!, y: (frame?.origin.y)!, width: (frame?.size.width)! + 100, height: (frame?.size.height)!)
            }, completion: nil)
```

That should set the size of the cell, but nothing happens.  Clicking the cell a second time, I see that the size of the cell is retained to the size+100 (disregard the fact that it would grow every time - just trying to get it to work right now).

In the sizeForItemAt function, any attempt to retrieve the cell returns nil.

```
collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section)
```

returns 3, but

```
collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
```

returns nil.  Why?

**How can I get the cell for that collection view with the given index path in the scope of sizeForItemAt:**???

Answer (score 1):

Apparently sizeForItemAt gets called before cellForItem.

Answer (score 0):

Are sure indexPath.row < 3 ? Because if not then it will return nil. Put a breakpoint in cellForItem and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, it was definitely 0.  The problem I was having was, I was looking at the execution of that code before the first .reloadData() had run its course and all delegates had been called.  In other words, the table hadn't yet been populated with data.